# Function takes same value at least twice

Tags: calculus

I have the following exercise from the book Advanced Calculus by Buck (exercise 12, section 2.4):

Show that any real-valued function defined on the set consisting of the nonnegative $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ axes must take the same value at least twice.

I don't know how to prove this because I think the proposition is missing some hypothesis. A strictly increasing function comes to my mind as a counter-example. Any help?

Comment: The function is defined on the axes, i.e., on three rays sharing a common point. What does "strictly increasing" mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim, as stated, is false. Consider, for instance, the function 
$$
f(x, y, z) = \begin{cases}
\arctan(x) & x > 0 \\
12 + \arctan(y) & y > 0 \\
37 + \arctan(z) & z > 0 \\
0 & (x, y, z) = (0, 0, 0)
\end{cases}.
$$
If you add the hypothesis that the function be continuous, then maybe it's a true statement, but I leave it to you to determine whether that's true or not.

Hint: apply the intermediate value theorem to the origin and a point on each axis in turn.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote the proposition as it appears on the book and that is why I had the doubt. I will try it considering continuity!

Comment: Good job doubting the textbook! Authors are human, too, and make mistakes, and doubting everything is a good skill for a reader.